# com.paypal.core.rest.PayPalRESTException:Read timed out

Tags: scala, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am using paypal for payment in my project. It works for **visa card** and **mastercard** and payment was successfully done.

```
private def doFinalPayment(payment: Payment, payer: Payer, accessToken: String): Payment = {    
val apiContext = new  APIContext(accessToken)  
var objPay=payment   
apiContext.setConfigurationMap(sdkConfig)   
try {
      objPay = objPay.create(apiContext)//Exception Occur here
      // some code here...........

       } catch {
     case e: PayPalRESTException => {
       println("EXCEPTION IN DO FINAL PAYMENT METHOD")
       val msg = e.getMessage
       println(e)
       println(msg)
     }   
   }    
objPay 
}
```

But with **American Express** & **Discover** card it gives me the following exception:

```
EXCEPTION IN DO FINAL PAYMENT METHOD  
com.paypal.core.rest.PayPalRESTException:Read timed out
Read timed out
```

I am using these library dependencies......

```
"com.paypal.sdk" % "paypal-core" % "1.5.2",
  "com.paypal.sdk" % "rest-api-sdk" % "0.7.1",
  "com.paypal.sdk" % "invoicesdk" % "2.4.106",
  "com.paypal.sdk" % "adaptivepaymentssdk" % "2.5.106",
  "com.paypal.sdk" % "adaptiveaccountssdk" % "2.4.106",
  "com.paypal.sdk" % "permissionssdk" % "2.3.106",
  "com.stripe" % "stripe-java" % "1.7.1",
  "com.sparkjava" % "spark-core" % "1.1.1",
   "com.paypal.sdk" % "merchantsdk" % "2.1.96"
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? (Complete error message? More details on the exception?)
Is the error listed in the [Paypal API documentation][1]?
Why library are you using? From the tags (and the code snippet) you use, I assume you use Scala and the Play Framework.

  [1]: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/%20%22Paypal%20API%20error%20codes

Comment: The url got mingled. This one should work: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/

Comment: till now i am not getting any new answer or idea to anyone

Answer (score 2):

American Express and Discover sometimes have longer processing times. If you are using the REST SDK as your base, the http.connectiontimeout variable is set to 30 seconds. You should increase that to at least 60 (and possibly higher if you still get timeouts).

In Scala, you can set http.setRequestTimeoutInMs(6000) to increase the timeout to 60 seconds.

The SDK samples include a bootstrap.php file that sets an APIContext.

```
    // Use an ApiContext object to authenticate 
// API calls. The clientId and clientSecret for the 
// OAuthTokenCredential class can be retrieved from 
// developer.paypal.com

$apiContext = new ApiContext(
    new OAuthTokenCredential(
        '...',
        '...'
    )
);



// #### SDK configuration

// Comment this line out and uncomment the PP_CONFIG_PATH
// 'define' block if you want to use static file 
// based configuration

$apiContext->setConfig(
    array(
        'mode' => 'sandbox',
        'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,
        'log.LogEnabled' => true,
        'log.FileName' => '../PayPal.log',
        'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE'
    )
);
```

The http.ConnectionTimeOut field is where you want to look. Set that to 60 or higher.

Comment: @PayPal_MSI_Robert i am using "com.paypal.sdk" % "rest-api-sdk" % "0.7.1", where have to change http.connectiontimeout, i am not getting in which folder and file i will get this variable.

Comment: Edited answer to include example. @RishiDwivedi

Comment: How does the bootstrap.php help him with a scala project? It would be more helpful if you just say which properties need to be set (and if possible why and what they will do)

Comment: @PayPal_MSI_Robert not helping, i am searching for the same issue, please help

Comment: @PayPal_MSI_Robert as @Peanut says i don't have any `bootstrap.php`

Comment: we dont have any SDK samples

Comment: For Scala, you can set 'http.setRequestTimeoutInMs(6000)' to increase the timeout. This should allow AmEx to get back to you before the standard timeout.

Comment: `http.setRequestTimeoutInMs(6000)` where to set?